# gradle task syntax

Tags: gradle

What is the difference between below snip of code

```
task hello {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

and

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle has two phases: configuration and execution.

During configuration phase Gradle parses and executes build.script DSL code. During parsing, Gradle creates instances of tasks and executes their internal code in order to configure them.

In first example, `println` code will be executed immediately during this configuration process.

In second example, `doLast` closure will be added to the task. It will be executed only during execution phase.

To see the difference, modify the task:

```
task myTask {
   println 'hello'
   doLast {
      println 'hello again'
   }
}
```

The output will be

```
hello             <---- this was configuration phase
:myTask
hello again       <---- this was execution phase
```

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet of code should be:

```
task hello <<    {
   println 'Hello world!'
}
```

This implies:

- When you execute the Gradle hello, Gradle will lookup a task with
  that name in the default build script build.gradle. If Gradle finds
  the task, it executes the code with the Groovy engine .
- Every line of code (LOC) between the braces composes the task.
- The double << , is the shorthand to define a Gradle task, the
  longhand is thus:

  ```
  task hello {
      doLast {
           println 'Hello world!'
      }
   }
  ```

So, the second snippet of code is just a longhand of first snippet of code. The double << is the short form to define the doLast task’s block